# Godel's completeness theorem and Consistency of ZFC

Tags: logic, set-theory, first-order-logic

Is it necessary to assume the consistency of $\sf ZFC$ when we prove the completeness theorem? When we use the completeness theorem to show that Peano Arithmetic is consistent, the assumption of consistency of $\sf ZF$ is necessary?

I mean, whenever one says that the completeness theorem prove the consistency of a first-order theory, does he assume that $\sf ZF$ or $\sf ZFC$ is consistent?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the completeness theorem, in general, means that we want to equate syntax and semantics. For this we need a framework that can interpret semantics, usually this means set theory such as $\sf ZF$ or its relatives (but not only these!)

Now, you don't *have* to assume $\sf ZF$ is consistent for using the completeness theorem, because we are working *inside* $\sf ZF$, that is our meta-theory, as far as Peano is concerned.

But now you might want to ask, should we even use $\sf ZF$ as a meta-theory? Does it prove a contradiction or not? And in that case you need to assume its consistency in the meta-meta-theory, or work with a meta-meta-theory which is strong enough to prove it. But then you need to ask yourself, why is this meta-meta-theory is good enough, and well... it's turtles all the way down from there.

---

**TL;DR** No, you don't need to assume anything. But once you start digging into your meta-theory's meta-theory, i.e. the meta-meta-theory, you might want to add these assumptions.

Comment: Thank you, but can I ask you one more  question? If we don't allow ZFC as a meta theory,  then is it true that the completeness theorem is not a meta theorem, but a theorem in ZFC because in ZFC one can prove the theorem formally?

Comment: In general, the completeness theorem is a theorem of ZFC. Yes. When you're using ZFC as a meta-theory for some theory (e.g. PA), then it is a meta-theory, but when you're studying logic in ZFC, it is a theorem because ZFC is not your meta-theory, it's your theory.

Comment: The way of using ZFC as a meta theory to prove the completeness theorem is similar to that of using PA as a meta theory to prove incompleteness theorems, is it right?

Comment: Yes. That's correct.